# How to add EditText in listview and get its value dynamically in all the rows?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, scroll, android-edittext

I have Checkbox and EditText and a Textview in a listView. It gets value for the text view from a list. Checkbox will be checked dynamically. In the same way EditText also can be entered dynamically. Now my problem is, When i scroll the list view (up and down) after entering the text in the Edit text, I could not get the typed value. I check the check box also like that. But using the position, I set it correct. I Could not know How to set the EditText value to the list properly. Please help me. Here is my code:

main.xml: (Main xml for launch)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
android:id="@+id/my_list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="250px" />
<Button 
android:text="Save" 
android:id="@+id/btnSave" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml: (ListView Row)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/label"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@+id/label"
android:textSize="30sp"/>

<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/check"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<EditText 
android:text=""
android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
android:layout_width="150px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Model.Java: (It is the POJO class)

```
package com.checkboxlistview;

public class Model {

private String name;
private boolean selected;
private String address;

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Model(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

}
```

MyAdapter.Java: (This is used to Hold the view in the list view using the converter and holder)

```
package com.checkboxlistview;

import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> implements TextWatcher {

private final List<Model> list;
private final Activity context;
int listPosititon;

public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
    protected EditText address;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    listPosititon = position;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.check);
        viewHolder.address = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
        viewHolder.checkbox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
boolean isChecked) {
int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag(); 
//Here we get the position that we have  set for the checkbox using setTag.
list.get(getPosition).setSelected(
buttonView.isChecked()); 
// Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
}
});
        viewHolder.address.addTextChangedListener(this);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.label, viewHolder.text);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.check, viewHolder.checkbox);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.txtAddress, viewHolder.address);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position); // This line is important.

    viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
    if (list.get(position).getAddress() != null) {
        viewHolder.address.setText(list.get(position).getAddress() + "");
    } else {
        viewHolder.address.setText("");
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    list.get(listPosititon).setAddress(s.toString());
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

MainActivity.java (This is the activity):

```
package com.checkboxlistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
 ListView listView;
 Button btnSave;
    ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter;
    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
        btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this,getModel());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Name : "+list.get(i).getName() +" Selected: "+list.get(i).isSelected(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }


    private List<Model> getModel() {
        list.add(new Model("Linux"));
        list.add(new Model("Windows7"));
        list.add(new Model("Suse"));
        list.add(new Model("Eclipse"));
        list.add(new Model("Ubuntu"));
        list.add(new Model("Solaris"));
        list.add(new Model("Android"));
        list.add(new Model("iPhone"));
        list.add(new Model("Java"));
        list.add(new Model(".Net"));
        list.add(new Model("PHP"));
        return list;
    }
}
```

There is no error in the code. It runs well. I could maintain the checkbox position and display at the same position even I scroll up and down. But I could not get and set the EditText value properly. Please Help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can achieve this using the custom list view.

find the example of listview with edittext is [here](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/)

Comment: Hi Munish Kapoor, Thanks for your reply. It works for me. I used AddTextChangedListener to get the text from the EditText. But using your sample I came to know that, we need to use setOnFocusChangeListener. Thanks a lot. I was trying this for two days.

Comment: Hi Munish Kapoor, I have another issue in this check box and edittext with list view. When i click a checkbox, It has to focus on the particular row EditText. How to make it. Please help me out.

Comment: @MunishKapoor can You Help me TO add Text Watcher in in android ListView. If You have able to Give this question Answer Please Help me to add Text watcher in Dynamic List view in android.

Answer (score 1):

Easy and beautiful solution to handle EditText with listView:
(Does not require holder or RecycleView or anything else)

Brief explaination:

1) In getView method when you inflate the view, apply the myTextWatcher the editText. Pass this EditText to the myTextWatcher()

2) Inside getView Method find that EditText and set position as editText.setTag [Each time. not only when the view was inflated.]

3) Define MyTextWatcher. It should have reference to EditText on which it is applied.

4) myTextWatcher.onTextChanged() will read the tag set to the editText and do the required work

Modify your getView() method of Adapter class:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_row_layout,parent,false);
            EditText et = convertView.findViewById(R.id.idEditText);
            et.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(et));
        }

    //This is again required to find reference to EditText... so that 'position' can be applied on to it as 'tag' EACH time.    
    EditText editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idEditText);;

    //This tag will be used inside onTextChanged()
    editText.setTag(position);

}
```

Define your MyTextWatcher class as:

```
private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{
    //int position;
    EditText et;
    public MyTextWatcher(EditText editText){
        this.et = editText;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(et.getTag()!=null){
            // This is required to ensure EditText is edited by user and not through program
            if(et.hasFocus()){
                 int position = (int)et.getTag();
                 String newText = et.getText()+"";
                 //Implement your actions here........
                 //you can get require things/ views from listView.getChildAt(position).. 
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep viewHolder.address.setTag(position) and it works perfect cheers.

Adapter Class:

```
package com.qzick.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.qzick.R;
import com.qzick.model.Get_All_Class_Model;

public class Get_Class_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    protected ArrayList<Get_All_Class_Model> get_class_details;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    private int x = 1;

    public Get_Class_Adapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<Get_All_Class_Model> get_class_details) {
        this.get_class_details = get_class_details;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return get_class_details.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return get_class_details.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = this.inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_adapter_class_ll, parent, false);

            holder.textclass = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.text_class_ll);

            holder.txtid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_id_ll);

            holder.checkclass = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.check_class_LL);

            holder.edtsection = (EditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.edttxt_addsection_ll);

            holder.checkclass
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {

                            int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();

                            get_class_details.get(getPosition).setChecked(
                                    buttonView.isChecked());

                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.check_class_LL, holder.checkclass);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.edttxt_addsection_ll, holder.edtsection);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.checkclass.setTag(position);
        holder.edtsection.setTag(position);

        holder.edtsection.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                int pos = (Integer) holder.edtsection.getTag();

                get_class_details.get(pos).setEdtsections(s.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        holder.txtid.setText(get_class_details.get(position).getId());
        holder.textclass.setText(get_class_details.get(position).getText());
        holder.edtsection.setText(get_class_details.get(position)
                .getEdtsections());

        holder.textclass.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                x++;

                if (x % 2 == 0) {
                    holder.checkclass.setChecked(false);

                } else {
                    holder.checkclass.setChecked(true);
                }

            }
        });

        holder.checkclass.setChecked(get_class_details.get(position)
                .isChecked());
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView textclass, txtid;`enter code here`
        CheckBox checkclass;
        EditText edtsection;
    }
}
```