# How can I add Edittext into Checkbox?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-edittext

I have some problem about how to add edittext into a checkbox. This is my code which use to create checkbox.

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(OrderActivity.this);
                    EditText et = new EditText(OrderActivity.this);
                    cb.setText(obj.getString("color") + "  | PO : " + obj.getString("po") + "  | SO : " + obj.getString("so") + " | Available : " + obj.getString("dozen"));
                    cb.setId(i+10);
                    cb.setWidth(150);
                    ll.addView(cb);
                }
```

How can I add edittext into that checkbox ?

And this is the result capture image.

[image]

Thank you before.

Comment: Do you want to check the checkbox or show the text in the editext in the checkbox?

Comment: I want to add edittext into every checkbox @CrazyAndroid

Comment: You can check your checkbox @Nicholas Pratma,there isn't any provision for writing text inside it.

Answer (score 0):

in CheckBox u can't Edit your checkbox there is no feature available in android, so you will have to create customize listView and use EditText in place of checkbox...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `listview`. Add checkbox and edittext in row.xml. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929971/how-to-add-edittext-in-listview-and-get-its-value-dynamically-in-all-the-rows)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use Recyclerview with checkbox,Because in listview you need to maintain checkbox arraylist, so better use recyclerview with checkbox and and create custom view for edittext See [RecyclerView with CheckBox](http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/recyclerview-with-checkbox-example.html)