# EditText not working inside ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-edittext

My ListView consists of three EditTexts and a TextView, and it is populated by an ArrayList. When a text is edited, I want it to update and save to the ArrayList. I tried following the guide linked here: https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/ from [How to add EditText in listview and get its value dynamically in all the rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929971/how-to-add-edittext-in-listview-and-get-its-value-dynamically-in-all-the-rows) but I'm having a lot of issues.

The error I'm getting now is that under public Void onFocusChange it says events needs to be declared final. If I declare it "final" in front of the EditText where I intialize it, it says "cannot assign a value to final variable events". I vaguely understand why I'm getting these errors, but in the guide they must work fine as is.

This is the Custom adapter I have for my ListView:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

ArrayList<Event> mobileArrayList;


public CustomAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Event> events){
    super(context, 0, events);
    this.mobileArrayList = events;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    Event event = mobileArrayList.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listview_row, parent, false);
        holder.caption = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.events)
    }

    EditText events = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.events);
    EditText start = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.start);
    EditText end = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.end);
    TextView day = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.day);

    events.setText(event.getSummary());
    start.setText("Start Date: " +event.getDateStart());
    end.setText("End Date: " + event.getDateEnd());
    day.setText(event.getDayOfTheWeek());

    holder.caption.setId(position);

    holder.caption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus){
                final int position = v.getId();
                final EditText events = (EditText) v;
                mobileArrayList.get(position).setSummary(events.getText().toString());

            }
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder{
    EditText caption;
}
```

}

My setSummary method in my Events class:

```
public void setSummary(String s){
    this.summary = s;
}
```

I should note "event" is my POJO declared in the first line under view and "events" is an EditText object. I tried to follow the guide closely but I do not have a lot of experience and am not 100% sure what it is all doing. Also, this would only accomdate for one of my editTexts and I would repeate the onClickListener for the other two.  Thank you

Comment: this may help https://github.com/gosemathraj/GridViewEdittext

Comment: Sadly it is required I do this with ListView

Comment: listview , gridview or be any other viewgroup the core logic would be same

Comment: The "events" inside onFocusChange() should be a local variable, so that line should be "final EditText events = (EditText) v;". Hope that help!

Comment: That makes sense. However now my program doesn't even launch and crashes immediately

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814620/listview-with-a-custom-adapter-every-other-item-element-are-duplicates/29822061#29822061

Comment: It now gives me an NPE on the first line under 'if(convertView == null)', which is extra strange because earlier the line 'EditText events = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.events)' was working perfectly fine